# Trouble creating PID file in systemd service script

Tags: systemd, debian-jessie, systemctl

I'm trying to get RipRight installed on Debian, for which there doesn't appear to be any pre-built package. I'm having difficulty getting a systemd script working to start/stop RipRight running as a daemon because it can't write the PID file to `/run`.

I went through the usual configure/make/make install. I also created a `ripright` user/group and added `ripright` to the `cdrom` group.

Here is the systemd script I placed in `/etc/systemd/system/ripright.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=RipRight

[Service]
Type=forking
PrivateTmp=yes
User=ripright
Group=ripright

RuntimeDirectory=ripright
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0750

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ripright \
    --daemon \
    --w32-filenames \
    --require-art \
    --folder-art folder.png \
    --output-file "%B/%D/%C - %N %T.flac" \
    "/opt/ripright/data"
PIDFile=/var/run/ripright/ripright.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I used the recently-added `RuntimeDirectory` directive in the script to create a `/run/ripright` folder with `ripright` as the owner. This directory gets created when I run:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start ripright
```

In a separate window:

```
# ls -lhrt /run
...
drwxr-x---  2 ripright ripright   40 Jan  5 20:52 ripright
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root      400 Jan  5 20:52 systemd
# ls -lahrt /run/ripright
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     540 Jan  5 20:52 ..
drwxr-x---  2 ripright ripright  40 Jan  5 20:52 .
# su - ripright
$ cd /run/ripright
$ pwd
/run/ripright
$ echo test > one.txt
$ cat one.txt
test
$ rm one.txt
$ exit
```

I believe my `systemctl start` command does not return due to this and instead hangs. After a minute or so, it times out with:

```
# systemctl start ripright
Job for ripright.service failed. See 'systemctl status ripright.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Here is the output of the recommended commands:

```
# systemctl status ripright.service
● ripright.service - RipRight
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ripright.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2017-01-05 20:54:40 EST; 55s ago
  Process: 35396 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ripright --daemon --w32-filenames --require-art --folder-art folder.png --output-file %B/%D/%C - %N %T.flac /opt/ripright/data (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 33287 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Jan 05 20:53:10 ripperd ripright[35397]: Started daemon mode (v0.11)
Jan 05 20:53:10 ripperd ripright[35398]: Waiting for a CD (/dev/cdrom)
Jan 05 20:54:40 ripperd systemd[1]: ripright.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 05 20:54:40 ripperd systemd[1]: Failed to start RipRight.
Jan 05 20:54:40 ripperd systemd[1]: Unit ripright.service entered failed state.

# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Thu 2017-01-05 00:30:29 EST, end at Thu 2017-01-05 20:54:40 EST. --
Jan 05 20:52:00 ripperd ripright[35380]: Waiting for a CD (/dev/cdrom)
Jan 05 20:52:59 ripperd su[35385]: Successful su for ripright by root
Jan 05 20:52:59 ripperd su[35385]: + /dev/pts/1 root:ripright
Jan 05 20:52:59 ripperd su[35385]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user ripright by vagrant(uid=0)
Jan 05 20:53:10 ripperd ripright[35397]: Started daemon mode (v0.11)
Jan 05 20:53:10 ripperd ripright[35398]: Waiting for a CD (/dev/cdrom)
Jan 05 20:53:33 ripperd su[35385]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user ripright
Jan 05 20:54:40 ripperd systemd[1]: ripright.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 05 20:54:40 ripperd systemd[1]: Failed to start RipRight.
-- Subject: Unit ripright.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ripright.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 05 20:54:40 ripperd systemd[1]: Unit ripright.service entered failed state.
```

If I comment out the PIDFile directive in the systemd service script:

```
#PIDFile=/var/run/ripright/ripright.pid
```

Then I have no problems, but also no PID file as recommended for a service type of forking:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start ripright
# ps -ef | grep ripright
ripright  35438      1  0 21:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/ripright --daemon --w32-filenames --require-art --folder-art folder.png --output-file %B/%D/%C - ripright %T.flac /opt/ripright/data
ripright  35439  35438  0 21:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/ripright --daemon --w32-filenames --require-art --folder-art folder.png --output-file %B/%D/%C - ripright %T.flac /opt/ripright/data
root      35442  31942  0 21:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep ripright
root@ripperd:~# systemctl status ripright
● ripright.service - A minimal CD ripper for Linux modeled on autorip.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ripright.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-01-05 21:03:11 EST; 13s ago
  Process: 35437 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ripright --daemon --w32-filenames --require-art --folder-art folder.png --output-file %B/%D/%C - %N %T.flac /opt/ripright/data (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 35438 (ripright)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ripright.service
           ├─35438 /usr/local/bin/ripright --daemon --w32-filenames --require...
           └─35439 /usr/local/bin/ripright --daemon --w32-filenames --require...

Jan 05 21:03:11 ripperd ripright[35438]: Started daemon mode (v0.11)
Jan 05 21:03:11 ripperd ripright[35439]: Waiting for a CD (/dev/cdrom)
# ls -la /run/ripright
total 0
drwxr-x---  2 ripright ripright  40 Jan  5 21:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     540 Jan  5 21:04 ..
# systemctl stop ripright
```

Interestingly enough, when I brought `PIDFiles` back in and commented out `User` and `Group` to run ripright as root, daemon-reloading and then starting the script still hangs:

```
#User=ripright
#Group=ripright
PIDFile=/var/run/ripright/ripright.pid
```

The same thing happens if I leave `User` and `Group` commented out and set `PIDFile` to produce the PID file directly in the /run directory (noting /var/run is simply a symlink to /run in Debian Jessie):

```
#User=ripright
#Group=ripright
#PIDFile=/var/run/ripright/ripright.pid
PIDFile=/run/ripright.pid
```

Note in all cases I can press Ctrl+C during the hang and the ripright daemon will continue to run; however, if I let the start time out, it'll stop the daemon before printing the error and returning.

I also went through [this post](https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/93-Handling-varrun-with-systemd.html) and its comments. The initial approach of using `ExecStartPre` had the same results; I did not get far with using `tmpfiles.d` as I couldn't find any information on how to make the changes take effect without rebooting. I tried `mount -a` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: How did you configure ripright to create a PID file? I could not find this anywhere in your question.

Comment: I didn't. The application needs to create the PID file? I see nothing in ripright's documentation or options, and it doesn't look like the source code is doing this at all. What if the application isn't written to create a PID file? Am I supposed to do so in the systemd service script, or in some wrapper script?

Comment: If the ripright program doesn't create a PID file, then you don't need to do anything. See http://serverfault.com/a/817560/126632

Comment: Looks like this will work for me; if you want to formulate this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking if systemd will create a PID file for the daemon, it will not, per:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PidFile=

> PIDFile=
>
> Takes an absolute file name pointing to the PID file of this daemon. Use > of this option is recommended for services where Type= is set to forking.
>   systemd will read the PID of the main process of the daemon after start-up 
>   of the service. systemd will not write to the file configured here, although 
>   it will remove the file after the service has shut down if it still exists.

It might be better to leave it blank and try using GuessMainPID=.

Comment: This is the answer. remove /run form your PID file path

Answer (score 6):

Regrettably, systemd won't create a PID file for a non-forking service even if you specify a `PIDFile=` line in the service's unit file. But you may be able to cheat with a `ExecStartPost=` line, such as:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'umask 022; pgrep YOURSERVICE > /var/run/YOURSERVICE.pid'
```

Comment: systemd doesn't create PID files at all. That's the responsibility of the service. As discussed previously, that's not what `PIDFile=` is for.

Comment: Alas, it's too bad that systemd can't be requested to write/delete pidfiles for `Type=simple` services as it is most in possession of the info to do so.