# systemctl shows inactive / dead, but service is running

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I would like to manage a TeamSpeak 3 server with systemd (systemctl).

When I start / stop / restart the TeamSpeak 3 server using systemctl command, systemctl is returning the correct status:

```
$ systemctl status ts3server.service
● ts3server.service - TeamSpeak 3 Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ts3server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-02-12 23:15:18 CET; 1min 11s ago
 Main PID: 842 (ts3server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ts3server.service
           └─842 ./ts3server inifile=ts3server.ini

Feb 12 23:15:18 hostname.local systemd[1]: Starting TeamSpeak 3 Server...
Feb 12 23:15:18 hostname.local ts3server_startscript.sh[838]: Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
Feb 12 23:15:18 hostname.local ts3server_startscript.sh[838]: TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file
Feb 12 23:15:18 hostname.local systemd[1]: Started TeamSpeak 3 Server.
```

But when the service is stopped otherwise (eg. through an automated update process) and then started again - without systemctl - the `systemctl status` command returns an incorrect status:

```
$ systemctl status ts3server.service
● ts3server.service - TeamSpeak 3 Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ts3server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-02-11 03:15:16 CET; 1 day 19h ago
Condition: start condition failed at Mon 2019-02-11 03:15:16 CET; 1 day 19h ago
           └─ ConditionPathExists=!/home/teamspeak/.update.lock was not met
  Process: 21740 ExecStop=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 29220 ExecStart=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29224 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

The PID file exists in this moment:

```
$ stat /home/teamspeak/ts3server.pid
  File: /home/teamspeak/ts3server.pid
  Size: 4              Blocks: 8          EA Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d     Inode: 534471      Symbolic Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/teamspeak)   Gid: ( 1001/teamspeak)
Access    : 2019-02-12 23:15:09.192927211 +0100
Modified: 2019-02-12 23:15:09.188927218 +0100
Changed   : 2019-02-12 23:15:09.188927218 +0100
 Birth    : -
```

The process with this PID is running and I can connect to this TeamSpeak 3 server.

`/home/teamspeak/.update.lock` exists while the automated update process is running. After the update, the file is removed / deleted and does NOT exist anymore.

`systemctl` shows the correct status, when I kill the running service PID as `systemctl` restarts the service using systemd correct later.

Here is my `/etc/systemd/system/ts3server.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak 3 Server
After=network.target mysqld.service
ConditionPathExists=!/home/teamspeak/.update.lock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=ts3server.service

[Service]
User=teamspeak
Group=teamspeak
WorkingDirectory=/home/teamspeak/
ExecStart=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh start
ExecStop=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
ExecReload=/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh restart
PIDFile=/home/teamspeak/ts3server.pid
Restart=always
Type=forking
```

Why can `systemctl` not return the correct status, although the TeamSpeak 3 server is started correct on a different way?

Comment: What was the running PID then?

Comment: I've just reproduced the issue: `su -c "/home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh status" teamspeak -s /bin/bash` returns `Server is running`, but `systemctl status ts3server.service` is returning `inactive (dead)` with `start condition failed` and `Main PID: 19930 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`. The PID file `/home/teamspeak/ts3server.pid` contains this PID: `20064`

Comment: Of course, systemd didn't start it! Please start over and update your question accordingly.

Comment: But shouldn't systemd check the `PIDFile` and see, that it's up and running?

Comment: No, systemd does not check the `PIDFile`. That's not [what it's for](https://serverfault.com/a/817560/126632).

Comment: If you have a wrapper script to start the service, you might be interested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622902/how-can-i-determine-within-a-shell-script-whether-it-is-being-called-by-system

Answer (score 3):

You should change the `Type` to `simple` in your unit file and it will work. IIRC `forking` requires an explicit call of `fork()` method, while you start it from a bash script and there simply is no `fork()` call.

Comment: This does unfortunately not solve the issue. It is still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your "why" question is that systemd is looking for the PID that it knows of (842 in your example output above), it does not track the service's own PID information.  If that process is no longer running, systemd has no idea what's going on with the process.  Nor can it restart it (since the ports would already be bound to by the new instance).

Probably a cleaner way to do the upgrade is

1. Use systemctl to stop the service
2. Perform the update, and then
3. Use systemctl start the process.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to specify `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes` and do not specify `PIDFile=`

**Minimal example:**

```
[Unit]
Description=service that is restarted by externalities.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/startup.sh
ExecStop=/stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Documentation calls it "[Stoppable oneshot service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)"

> *Similarly to the oneshot services, there are sometimes units that need to execute a program to set up something and then execute another to shut it down, but no process remains active while they are considered "started".*

But they don't consider the use case where the program that is started changes PID values even though it works for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

use `systemctl --user get-default` to get default target

```
$ systemctl --user get-default
default.target
```

change

```
WantedBy=default.target
```