# Systemd `ExecStartPost` timed out

Tags: systemd

I'm having trouble using `ExecStartPost` in a systemd service. Even with the following simple command:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "exit 0"
```

... when I start the service, I get a "time out" error:

```
start-post operation timed out. Stopping.
```

Here is my full service definition. `mbtileserver` is a blocking program, not a daemon.

```
[Unit]
Description=mbtileserver daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/home/crp/var/run/mbtileserver.pid
User=crp
Group=crp
WorkingDirectory=/home/crp
ExecStart=/home/crp/go/bin/mbtileserver -d /home/crp/tiles/ -p 8080 -s "eGJ0NwI9_OyxHEFvBcU-9zR6O89z_S0RNfIOSP3utSU"
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "exit 0"
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How do I create an `ExecStartPost` that doesn't time out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually discovered that the problem was that `PIDFile` didn't exist. This doesn't appear to be documented, but you need a valid `PIDFile` in order to use `ExecStartPost` (possibly *no* `PIDFile` would work, but an missing file definitely doesn't work).

Ironically, I was going to use `ExecStartPost` to *create* the pid file, but wanted to try it with something simple (originally had an `echo`) first.

Changing `ExecStartPost` to the following made the service work:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "pgrep -o mbtileserver > /home/crp/var/run/mbtileserver.pid"
```

Comment: Your program is supposed to create the PID file, not systemd. If your program doesn't create a PID file, then do not use the directive at all in your systemd unit.

Comment: I had known that, but it hadn't caused a problem _until_ I added `ExecStartPost`, which is what tripped me up.

Comment: Well, congrats, you found some undocumented behavior in systemd. It's probably worth a bug report, if only so the documentation can be fixed.

Comment: Good idea! I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Here's a bit more [background on PIDFile=](https://serverfault.com/a/817560/126632) that you might find useful.